# C# Concatenate strings using backslash

Tags: c#

I want to combine four variables like this :

`string  a,b,c,d;

string Qno = "a\b\c\d";`

How to do for above result?

Answer (score 7):

```
string Qno = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}", a,b,c,d);
```

or if you have the strings in an array you can use string.Join:

```
string Qno = string.Join("\\", myArray);
```

Comment: Starting with .NET 4, `string.Join`'s last parameter is `params string[] values` instead of `string[] values`. There is also an overload taking `params object[] values`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to build a file path? If you do, check out the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx) method:

```
string path = Path.Combine(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling to concat 'c:\folder' with '\' and subFolder... escaping the backslash left me with 'c:\folder\\subfolder'. Functionally fine, but not aesthetically... Path.Combine solves the problem.

Comment: Really helpful when defining a FileName separate from the Path and not needing to remember if the Path requires a trailing backslash or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
string str = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}", a, b, c, d);
```